# Does Qt 5.15.8 expose implementation/headers of OpenSSL to clients?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

We have a very large application (1,200 projects, 10+MLoc).  Currently, we use Qt 5.15.8 dynamically linked and OpenSSL dynamic libraries loaded when needed.  We also use gRPC (which uses OpenSSL).  Other parts of our application (our own code) use OpenSSL directly.

Any extra dependencies between libraries create big difficulties when we need to update one library, sometimes forcing dozens of libraries to also be updated. With an application our size, these simultaneous updates are both extremely difficult and disruptive to developers.

We are considering switching to using static versions of OpenSSL.  This would allow us to update OpenSSL in one application area or third party library at a time.  However, I need to be very careful about ODR violations or mixing OpenSSL versions.  Some hypothetical ways this could happen:

- Public QtNetwork headers include OpenSSL headers.
- OpenSSL functions can legally be called in Qt clients, then OpenSSL structures somehow passed to Qt.

I am not an expert in this area, and I don't know if this is a problem.  Can anybody tell me if Qt provides isolation around OpenSSL so that my application can use static version(s) of OpenSSL safely?

(Our application runs on Linux and Windows.)

Comment: So you want to use both static and dynamic versions of OpenSSL? And what do you mean by "isolation"?